# Parsing JSON when property value can be a scalar string or an array of objects

Tags: apex, json, httprequest

I'm working on an integration to go spot check, and one of the problems I've run into is that the data type for one of the json properties can be different depending on the question type.

Here is the relevant json:

```
{
    "id": 140078048,
    "mission_response_id": 2668091,
    "task_id": 1766994,
    "value": [
        {
            "s3": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/gospotcheck-mobile-production/mission_45591/ios-0-1766994-1459930809-0001-picture.jpg",
            "filepicker": "https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/pPxln8MkRLyjxJWXGJU6"
        }
    ],
    "created_at": "2016-04-06T05:10:38.008-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-04-06T05:11:08.980-04:00",
    "type": "TaskResponse::Picture",
    "context": null
},
{
    "id": 140078045,
    "mission_response_id": 2668091,
    "task_id": 1766990,
    "value": "No",
    "created_at": "2016-04-06T05:10:38.002-04:00",
    "updated_at": "2016-04-06T05:10:38.002-04:00",
    "type": "TaskResponse::YesNo",
    "context": null
},
```

You can clearly see how in one response `value` is just a string where in the other response it's an array of values.

Here is my attempt at catching both types, as it is now i appears to process the first response but not the 2nd.

```
public class MissionResponse{
    public String id { get; set; }
    public String mission_response_id { get; set; }
    public String task_id { get; set; }
    public String created_at { get; set; }
    public String updated_at { get; set; }
    public String type { get; set; }
    public list<Value> value{ get; set; }
    // public Value value { get; set; }
    // public list<String> value;

    // public void setvalue(String valueStr){
    //  // this.value = new list<String>{valueStr};
    //  map<String, String> strMap = new map<String,String>();
    //  strMap.put('0', valueStr);
    //  this.value = strMap;
    // }

    // public void setvalue(map<String,String> valueList){
    //  this.value = valueList;
    // }

    // public map<String,String> getvalue(){
    //  return this.value;
    // }

    public MissionResponse(){
        system.debug('new mission response');
    }

}

public class value{


    public value(){

    }

    public value(String valueStr){
        system.debug('string');
    }

    public value(list<String> valueLst){
        system.debug('list');
    }       

    public value(map<String, String> valueMap){
        system.debug('map');
    }

    public value(sObject valueObj){
        system.debug('object');
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on getting this parsed correctly? I'm leaning towards modifying my request to do it by answer type and then have a separate class that would handle the single value or array of values, but I would prefer to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: Is the commented out code relevant to the question? If not, its probably a good idea to [edit] it out,  or to [edit] the comments out if it is.

Comment: I wanted to leave the commented code in this case to show the other ways I've attempted to construct the class, mainly as a point of reference to build the complete picture. Custom getters/setters, Single wrapper class, list of wrapper classes, etc.

Comment: Seems like you need to test whether the value is an array/object or string before processing the response by calling one of two different methods/classes.

Comment: Alternatively, if you're going to use a class for Value, Use a no argument constructor, then have a second one that takes a string, and a 3rd that takes an object or array and pass your value to the Value class.

Comment: I tried the class with multiple parameters, the problem it seems is that deserialize is first attempting to compare the data type and assign the value before calling the constructor / setter. I think in this case i may have to make separate requests for each data type - or - work with the JSON parser which is not exactly something I'm super excited to do..